# how can I check/test 2 conditions then execute a specific list of commands I tried case, I tried if, I tried for not working

Tags: scripting, case

sorry if it was confusing.

here is what the script needs to be doing

I input 2 values.

DB Server name= `192.168.1.1`

DB schema = `My_DB_schema`

Then I need a method to execute  some command when those 2 values are there

sample would be:

if the DB server name and DB schema are

```
192.168.1.1  
My_DB_schema
```

execute

```
command 1
command 2
```

I tried with a case statement but I think it will only test for one condition.

Thank you

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want your code to be doing. You're reading something into `SERVER`, but you almost immediately assign IP-addresses to this variable depending on the value of `$DB_NAME`, discarding the provided value.

Comment: General note: avoid asking users for input. That just makes it much more likely they will make a mistake, it means your script cannot be repeated or automated and is just harder to use. Pass what you need as arguments instead. That said, please [edit] your question and explain a bit more clearly. What are the conditions? How do they change? What combinations of conditions do you need to be able to handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but you can concat several variables (using some separator if you know this is not part of the values, e.g. `:`).

For example something like

```
SERVER=foo
DB_NAME=bar

case "$SERVER:$DB_NAME" in
  foo:bar)
    echo "foobar"
    ;;
  foo:*)
    echo "foo"
    ;;
  *:bar)
    echo "bar"
    ;;
esac
```

So you have one case where the server is `foo` and the database is `bar`, one where the server is `foo` and the database can be anything, and one where the server can be anything and the database is `bar`.

You should be able to match any combinations you are interested in in this way.

You can use these two "conditions" (`SERVER` and `DB_NAME`), but also three, or four, or as many as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Naively, you could simply do

```bsh
db_name=...some-database-name...
db_host=...some-database-host...

if [ "$db_host" = '192.168.1.1' ] &&
   [ "$db_name" = 'My_DB_schema' ]
then
    command-1
    command-2
fi
```

User dirkt [shows how to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/658395/116858) concatenate the two variables into a *single* string and then how to use a `case` statement to test this string.  I would personally not do that as you *theoretically* could have values like `some:host` and `my:name`, and you would not know what part came from which variable in the string `some:host:my:name`, *in the most general case*.  In situations where you have full control over the contents of your variables, this is a more acceptable solution.